# join in list with many data in array not working python

Tags: python, string, pandas, list

I fail to convert list to string with join in python

I tried to join str replace but still not working

```
data2['hadis'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.lower() for x in x.split()))
data2['hadis'].head()
```

['perbuatan', 'tergantung', 'niatnya', 'balasan', 'tiaptiap', 'tergantung', 'diniatkan', 'barangsiapa', 'niat', 'hijrahnya', 'dunia', 'digapainya', 'perempuan', 'dinikahinya', 'hijrahnya', 'diniatkan']

['terkadang', 'kepadaku', 'suara', 'gemerincing', 'lonceng', 'berat', 'buatku', 'terhenti', 'mengerti', 'terkadang', 'malaikat', 'menyerupai', 'lakilaki', 'berbicara', 'kepadaku', 'ikuti', 'aisyah', 'sungguh', 'turunnya', 'wahyu', 'beliau', 'dingin', 'terhenti', 'dahi', 'beliau', 'mengucurkan', 'keringat']

```
for i, kalimat in enumerate (data2['hadis']):
print(kalimat)
```

i hope the result like this

perbuatan tergantung niatnya balasan tiaptiap tergantung diniatkan barangsiapa niat hijrahnya dunia digapainya perempuan dinikahinya hijrahnya diniatkan

terkadang kepadaku suara gemerincing lonceng berat buatku terhenti mengerti terkadang malaikat menyerupai lakilaki berbicara kepadaku ikuti aisyah sungguh turunnya wahyu beliau dingin terhenti dahi beliau mengucurkan keringat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert a list containing strings into a separate string, you can use `string.join()`

```
a = ["Hello", "world", "my", "world"]
print("".join(a))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Helloworldmyworld
```

Comment: If you are using python 3.x then you can use `print(*a)`